# MySQL MATH AGAINST returns a score of 0

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I've got this table called `Names`:

```
ID | name
-----------------
1 | nobody
2 | brian
3 | john
4 | greg
```

I've altered the table as such:

```
ALTER TABLE Names ADD FULLTEXT index_name(name);
```

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT *, (MATCH (name) AGAINST ('brian')) As score FROM Names;
```

I get the following result:

```
1 | nobody | 0
2 | brian | 1.0861...
3 | john | 0
4 | greg | 0
```

But when I do this:

```
SELECT *, (MATCH (name) AGAINST ('bria')) As score FROM Name;
```

Or

```
SELECT *, (MATCH (name) AGAINST ('bria*')) As score FROM Name;
```

I get:

```
1 | nobody | 0
2 | brian | 0
3 | john | 0
4 | greg | 0
```

`brian` is not in more than 50% of my queries and is certain not a stopword, so not sure what's going on.

Comment: Full text search attempts to use the search term as a natural language phrase; this is useful for large bodies of test, but probably not so much for names.

Comment: Isn't that where * comes in? I thought that's supposed to act as a wildcard so you don't need complete phrases for your search term.